# Row-wise average of last n data available columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows;

| id | jan | feb | mar | apr | may |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 30 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 10 | 20 | 50 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 |  |  |  | 70 | 50 |
| 4 |  | 30 | 40 |  |  |

I want to get the row-wise average of last two columns (only where data available)

Expected output is as follows;

| id | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **10 | 30 ** |  |  |  | 20 |
| 2 | 10 | 20 | 50 | **50 | 60** | 55 |
| 3 |  |  |  | **70 | 50** | 60 |
| 4 |  | **30 | **40 |  |  | 35 |

My actual data frame has larger n number of columns and I can not hardcode the column names as well.
How can I move forward with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Compute a mask to only keep the relevant cells with [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
N = 2
m = df.loc[:, ::-1].notna().cumsum(axis=1).le(N)

df['average'] = df.drop(columns='id').where(m).mean(axis=1)
```

You can also take advantage of [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get rid of the NaNs, then get the last N values per ID:

```
N = 2
df['average'] = (
 df.set_index('id').stack()
   .groupby(level='id')
   .apply(lambda x: x.tail(N).mean())
   .reindex(df['id']).values
)
```

Output:

```
   id   jan   feb   mar   apr   may  average
0   1  10.0  30.0   NaN   NaN   NaN     20.0
1   2  10.0  20.0  50.0  50.0  60.0     55.0
2   3   NaN   NaN   NaN  70.0  50.0     60.0
3   4   NaN  30.0  40.0   NaN   NaN     35.0
```

Comment: i'd expect the stack option to be more expensive

Comment: @sammywemmy could be, but the mask approach should be fast. And in any case, both might be faster than using `apply`.

Comment: I expect the mask approach to be fast ... D number of rows do not increase ... D functions used are not that expensive... But I've been proven wrong before  tho

Answer (score 1):

Using `agg` function

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 'jan':[10, 10, np.nan, np.nan],
                 'feb':[30, 20, np.nan, 30],
                 'mar':[np.nan, 50, np.nan, 40],
                 'apr':[np.nan, 50, 70, np.nan],
                 'may':[np.nan, 60, 50, np.nan],
                 })

N=2
df['LastN_Mean'] = df[df.columns[1:]].agg(lambda r: r[r.notna()][-N:].mean(), axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
   id   jan   feb   mar   apr   may  LastN_Mean
0   1  10.0  30.0   NaN   NaN   NaN        20.0
1   2  10.0  20.0  50.0  50.0  60.0        55.0
2   3   NaN   NaN   NaN  70.0  50.0        60.0
3   4   NaN  30.0  40.0   NaN   NaN        35.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
col1=df1.apply(lambda ss:ss.dropna().tail(2).mean(),1)
df1.assign(average=col1)
```

out：

```
   id   jan   feb   mar   apr   may  average
0   1  10.0  30.0   NaN   NaN   NaN     20.0
1   2  10.0  20.0  50.0  50.0  60.0     55.0
2   3   NaN   NaN   NaN  70.0  50.0     60.0
3   4   NaN  30.0  40.0   NaN   NaN     35.0
```